# Bootstrap 3 row too wide giving horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I make a simple row with a form-control without getting a horizontal scrollbar?

It seems that whatever I do with bootstrap 3, any "fluid" row that should be 100% is actually going beyond its container which introduces a horizontal scrollbar.  How do I stop this and make it fit into its container?

Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter something" id="foo" name="foo">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnb3q40g

Comment: Jake745 pointed out that it was a problem with the 3.0.0 version of bootstrap I was using.  Seems to be fixed in 3.2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is working fine with bootstrap 3.2.0

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/4CZQvispG5)

Comment: Interesting. I see it works on bootply.  However it has the scrollbars in my own html page (obviously more complex than this), and also it seems to have the problem on jsfiddle.  Perhaps something else is overriding the bootsrap styles?

Comment: The issue is with the 3.0.0 version you're using in the jsfiddle. You'll see the same issue if you change the BS version to 3.0.0 on Bootply http://www.bootply.com/4CZQvispG5

Comment: This briefly drove me crazy, since I used a Bootstrap variables generator meant for 3.0.0.  Luckily, upgrading to 3.3.7 worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
.container-fluid .row {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

For some reason when using `container-fluid` bootstrap doesn't take into account that it is using a negative margin on rows. So by adding the css above it will fix your issue.

Comment: that isn't a class. you miss out on the css style with `row:before`

Comment: Really late but I would recommend `.container-fluid>.row { }` over `.container-fluid .row { }` in case you have another normal container inside somewhere and want to put a normal row in.  Someone please correct me if it's a bad practice to nest containers.

Answer (score 0):

Demo -http://jsfiddle.net/MeycD/537/

You can do it in this way also if you want.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-5 col-lg-1">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-normal" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```